# Get Span value with Curl or Python (but when I do it's empty)?

Tags: python, html, windows, curl

I have this video surveillance software on Windows that has it's brower remote access, on PC's IP. (I can also view from remote since I have a public IP). I check the code in the browser UI and want to take these span values:

[code frow web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqLhx.jpg)

```
<span id="liveCameraCount">2</span>
<span id="totalCameraCount">2</span>
```

but, when I run this Curl code:

```
curl --user [user]:[password] http://[MY.PC.IP.ADDRESS.]:[PORT]
```

I get all the code, but the span that interest me are like that:

```
<span id="liveCameraCount"></span>
<span id="totalCameraCount"></span>
```

[response from Curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdqj1.jpg)

With no value in it... why?
I've try also Python code with module urllib and beautifulsoup, but same result

Comment: Chances are that this is a result of the User Agent string being checked by the camera to determine if you're using IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc.  It's changing what it returns based on what it thinks the capabilities of your web browser are.  Try using `-A` in your curl call to specify a [common User Agent string](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) and see what it returns then.

Comment: Nope. I've try it, now that's my code: `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" --user [user]:[password] http://[MY.PC.IP.ADDRESS.]:[PORT]` but I get the same result

Comment: Try in your browser with Javascript turned off. I'm guessing your camera's remote access does dynamic stuff on the page, which neither curl nor Python would execute.

Comment: curl is fetching pure html and your data is being loaded later by the javascript; python will not be able to run js code, use something like phantomjs, there is example that may be interesting https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js